# Can't select second item in tableview cell over uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

anyone please help me, I have a drop down but the I can't select it the second row. I can't figure out why, I try playing with bringSubviewsToFront or back. I try using layer.zPosition it still can't select the second row, but when I choose the first row it work. is it my auto layout setup incorrectly?

here is my ui and code setup

[image: dropdownshit]

```
// This is my custom Button

class GDropdownSchedule: UIButton {
    let headerLbl   = GTitleLabel(name: "Schedule Type".localized(), fontSize: 13, color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.4588235294, green: 0.4941176471, blue: 0.5647058824, alpha: 1))
    let bodyLbl     = GSubtitleLabel(name: "Additional Note".localized(), fontSize: 16, color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.09803921569, green: 0.09803921569, blue: 0.09803921569, alpha: 1))
    let dropDownIV  = GIconImageView(img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "down-chevron"))
    var isOpen              = false
    let dropView    = DropDownView()
    var delegate: AddScheduleVCDelegate?
    var height: NSLayoutConstraint!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    private func configure() {
        backgroundColor     = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705882, green: 0.9764705882, blue: 0.9764705882, alpha: 1)
        layer.cornerRadius  = 5
        layer.borderWidth   = 1
        layer.borderColor   = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9411764706, green: 0.9411764706, blue: 0.9450980392, alpha: 1)
        dropView.completion = { text in
            self.bodyLbl.text = text
            self.bodyLbl.font = UIFont(name: "NunitoSans-Regular", size: 12)
            self.delegate?.toggleHide(selected: text)
            self.dismissDropDown()
        }
    }
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        addSubview(headerLbl)
        headerLbl.anchor(top: topAnchor, trailing: nil, bottom: nil, leading: leadingAnchor, topPadding: 10, rightPadding: 0, bottomPadding: 0, leftPadding: 10, width: 70, height: 18)
        addSubview(bodyLbl)
        bodyLbl.anchor(top: headerLbl.bottomAnchor, trailing: nil, bottom: bottomAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, topPadding: 2, rightPadding: 10, bottomPadding: 10, leftPadding: 10, width: 0, height: 0)
        addSubview(dropDownIV)
        dropDownIV.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019608, green: 0.3019607843, blue: 0.3568627451, alpha: 1)
        dropDownIV.anchor(top: nil, trailing: trailingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, leading: nil, topPadding: 0, rightPadding: 18, bottomPadding: 17, leftPadding: 0, width: 12, height: 10)
        addSubview(dropView)
        dropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dropView.layer.zPosition = 1
        height = dropView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            dropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerLbl.bottomAnchor),
            dropView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            dropView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isOpen == false {
            isOpen = true
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([height])
            if self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height > 150 {
                height.constant = 150
            } else {
                height.constant = dropView.tableView.contentSize.height
            }
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([height])
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.dropView.center.y += self.dropView.frame.height / 2
            })
        } else {
            isOpen = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([height])
            height.constant = 0
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([height])
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
                self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
    func dismissDropDown() {
        isOpen = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([height])
        height.constant = 0
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([height])
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
            self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
class DropDownView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    let tableView           = UITableView()
    var options             = [String]()
    var completion: ((String) -> Void)?
    var isHideSchedule      = false
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    private func configure() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705882, green: 0.9764705882, blue: 0.9764705882, alpha: 1)
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.delegate      = self
        tableView.dataSource    = self
        tableView.anchor(top: topAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, leading: leadingAnchor, topPadding: 0, rightPadding: 0, bottomPadding: 0, leftPadding: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return options.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = options[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "NunitoSans-Regular", size: 12)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.09803921569, green: 0.09803921569, blue: 0.09803921569, alpha: 1)
        cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705882, green: 0.9764705882, blue: 0.9764705882, alpha: 1)
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        completion?(options[indexPath.row])
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}

// This is in my viewController, the chooseScheduleDropDown is my customButton
[chooseScheduleDropDown, entryView, chooseDateView, chooseClass, startTimeView, endTimeView, descriptionView, saveBtn].forEach {
            v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            scrollView.addSubview(v)
        }
        scrollView.insertSubview(entryView, belowSubview: chooseScheduleDropDown)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the hit-test mechanism

You add the dropView on the Button `GDropdownSchedule`

The layout is

```
        addSubview(dropView)
        dropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dropView.layer.zPosition = 1
        height = dropView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            dropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerLbl.bottomAnchor),
            dropView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            dropView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
```

From the looking and the existing code,

**dropView's frame is out of the Button `GDropdownSchedule`'s bounds Partly.**

So u can see it , and your clicking does not work.

---

**To override the hit-test mechanism is OK**

```
 class GDropdownSchedule: UIButton {

 // ...

   override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        // if the button is hidden/disabled/transparent it can't be hit
        if self.isHidden || !self.isUserInteractionEnabled || self.alpha < 0.01 { return nil }

        let dropViewF = dropView.frame


        var index = 9
        if bounds.contains(point){
            index = 0
        }

        if dropViewF.contains(point){
            index = 1
        }

        switch index {
        case 0:
            for subV in subviews.reversed(){
                let realPoint = subV.convert(point, from: self)
                let hit = subV.hitTest(realPoint, with: event)
                if let v = hit{
                    return v
                }
            }
            return self
        case 1:
            if dropView.alpha > 0.01{
                let realPoint = dropView.convert(point, from: self)
                let hit = dropView.hitTest(realPoint, with: event)
                if let v = hit{
                    return v
                }
            }
        default:
            ()
        }
        return nil
    }

 }
```

---

[From Apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest)

> **hitTest(_:with:)**
>
> This method traverses the view hierarchy by calling the
>   point(inside:with:) method of each subview to determine which subview
>   should receive a touch event.
>
> If point(inside:with:) returns true,
>   then the subview’s hierarchy is similarly traversed until the
>   frontmost view containing the specified point is found. If a view does
>   not contain the point, its branch of the view hierarchy is ignored.
>
> You rarely need to call this method yourself, but you might override
>   it to hide touch events from subviews.

Comment: Thank you.. Thank you!!!!!.. I have been figuring out this whole days, I don't know how thankful for me. T_T @dengApro